# Unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'm trying to run this python script using terminal in mac os x.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import re 
lept = open("NC_005823.gbk", "r+") 

 for line in lept :
   if re.match("unknown function", line ):
       print line
```

but it gives me this error:

```
 File "test.py", line 1
    {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1265\cocoasubrtf210
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

I can' t figure out what's wrong. All my code runs perfectly well on online editors. How do I fix this?

Comment: Save the file as plain text and not as rich text.

Comment: The encoding of the file is not what Python is expecting (ASCII on Python 2, UTF8 on Python 3).

Comment: Did you... save this as `rtf`?

Comment: converting to plain text worked, but now i'm getting this error:
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file test.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: The character `'\xe2'` should _not_ appear in your source code if it's truly plain ASCII text. I don't use Mac but I guess something weird happened when you converted from RTF to plain ASCII. I suggest you copy & paste your code from the top of this page into a fresh document, preferably in an editor that's intended for use by programmers so that you can't accidentally save it as RTF, etc. FWIW, a programmer's editor will give you colour-coded syntax highlighting (similar to what happens to code blocks here, but more powerful) which is very helpful.

Comment: @user2474041 did you actually read that link or just pasted here the error messages and let other people read and explain the contents to you? In that link it already tells you how to fix your problem.